# Angular 2 Module is available only after server is running

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I've an Angular 2 application, using Angular CLI and Webpack, where I'm using a external Angular 2 module called [angular2-swiper](https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular2-swiper), it's basically a wrapper to a library called Swiper.

I've to import a module in my AppModule called KSSwiperModule, but when I try to start my server with my code, it give me an error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: KSSwiperModule is not an NgModule`

But if I run without the import of this module, the server runs, and I put the import after it's running, it doesn't give any error and execute perfectly. (no, my app can't work without this module).

My code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {KSSwiperModule} from 'angular2-swiper';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SwiperComponent } from './swiper.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FlickityComponent } from "./flickity.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SwiperComponent,
    FlickityComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    KSSwiperModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Somebody know why it's happening and how to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks a guy from my work (Warren)!

The problem is with the `angular-cli` version. I was using `1.0.0-beta.22-1`, when i rolled back to `1.0.0-beta.19-3` it worked smoothly.